# Android TextView align inside of TableLayout

Tags: android, text, textview, alignment, tablelayout

I have a TableLayout with 3 columns,and the text in the first column is much bigger. What I want is that the textviews are aligned to the top of the TableRow. I have to do it programatically, because the table is dynamical, so it is also generated in the Java file.

[image]

My java:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;

public class B10o extends SherlockFragment {

String[] column1;
String[] column2;
String[] column3;
String[] textView1;
String[] textView2;
Intent intent;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Get the view from fragmenttab1.xml
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.b10o, container, false);

    intent = new Intent(getActivity(), B10so.class);
    final Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    TableLayout prices = (TableLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.table);
    String[] column1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.b10oo);
    String[] column2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.b10op1);
    String[] column3 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.b10op2);
    String[] textView1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.title);
    String[] textView2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.subtitle);
    prices.setStretchAllColumns(true);
    prices.bringToFront();
    for(int i = 0; i < column1.length; i++){
        TableRow tr =  new TableRow(getActivity());
        tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        TextView c1 = new TextView(getActivity());
        c1.setText(column1[i]);
        c1.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        c1.setTextSize(40);
        c1.setPadding(0, 0, 20, 0);
        TextView c2 = new TextView(getActivity());
        c2.setText(column2[i]);
        TextView c3 = new TextView(getActivity());
        c3.setText(column3[i]);
        c3.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        c3.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
        tr.addView(c1);
        tr.addView(c2);
        tr.addView(c3);
        prices.addView(tr);

    }
    TextView textView1t = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView1t.setText(textView1[0]);
    TextView textView2t = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textView2t.setText(textView2[0]);
    return view;
}

}
```

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your xml/code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done by using setGravity().
The code will look like this.

```
TextView c1 = new TextView(this);
c1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
```

Hope this is what you are looking for!

Comment: @Tamas Koos -- Can you please accept my answer if it has solved your problem? Thanks!

Comment: +1. And no, unfortunately i'm not able to except your answer as this was not my question. Good job on the formatting.

Comment: Yes, I saw that it was not your question :) I have updated my comment. Anyway, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by setting android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" for the last two textviews. The following code does what you requires.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="4"
                android:textSize="30dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="100,25" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="35" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I can't set it in the xml, because the java code creates the textviews.